# Angular - How to return a bool from a Subscription in my service-component?

Tags: angular, subscription

I have a login.service.ts, and my login.component.ts

In my login component, I have an input field, where the user inputs a username, and when he hits "login", we check if that
user name is valid with this call:

```
<button color="primary" mat-raised-button (click)="loadUserInfo(email.value)">
      continue
      <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon>
    </button>

loadUserInfo(userLogin: string) {
this.loginService.processLogin(userLogin);
}
```

which calls my service:

```
processLogin(loginId: string) {
return this.http.get("api/" + loginId).subscribe(
(user: User) => {

        this.userSub.next(user);
      },
      err => {
        console.error("Username not valid");
      }
    );
  }
```

I cannot wrap my head around the following:
If the call is unsuccessful, and there is no user with that username, how can I, in my `login.component.ts`, show a error message under the 
input field? I would need a bool or something, but the error handling is in the `service component`, so not really sure what is the best way

I would put under my input field this:

```
  <div *ngIf="userNotValid"> Error, this user doesn't exist</div>
```

But what should be the best way to handle this scenario? The users presses the button, the API returns the error, and now, how do I show an error in the login-component html file?
Thank you

Comment: You have to use a `BehaviorSubject` to store the state. And retrieve it in your template using the `async` pipe.

Comment: My first idea is to do the subscription in the component itself and change the state of `userNotValid` in the `subscribe` directly.

Comment: @Ploppy could you provide an example? thank you

Comment: @tenkmilan sadly the logic must stay in the service! Otherwise I would have done it like that

Comment: I agree with tenkmilan, use an observable in the login service and subscribe to that in the component. When login is not successful, the login service will emit the error and the component will listen to that and change the car

Comment: @DanielRead I really didn't want to do this, I know I could make it a boolean Observable and subscribe directly in my component, but that would mean changing the logic of other components, but if you all agree that it's the cleanest way, I ll change my logic I guess

Comment: @AJ989 yeah i do this for my app and it actually comes very handy because then any screen on the app can listen for when the user logs in successfully (i allow the user to bounce around the app without being logged in & make certain features pop open the login screen). Certain components listen for when the user successfully logs in via the observable and refresh themselves to show logged in content

Comment: @DanielRead ok could you show me an example of the cleanest way to convert that subscription to an observable, while keeping the logic that, if there is a valid user, it will call next() on the BehaviourSubject that stores the current user?

Comment: @AJ989 turning off for the night but if u don’t have an answer in the morning I’ll type one up for ya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as many suggested, I should make it an observable in my service, and subscribe to it from my component, I didn't want to do this as I would need to change other stuff as well, but if it's the cleanest way I just might do it.

Would it make sense, doing it like this, so it both returns a boolean, and if the User is valid, it will fire next() to my `behaviourSubject` that stores the current user?

```
processLogin(loginId: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get("api/" + loginId).pipe(map(
      (info: UserInfo) => {
        console.log("userinfo:", info);
        return info;
      }),
      catchError(err => of(null as UserInfo))
    ).pipe(tap(
      uInfo => {
        this.userSub.next(uInfo);
      }
    ),
    map(u => u != null)
    );
  }
```

am I doing this correctly? Or could I improve it? 
In my view, now I have both things I wanted, a Boolean as return, and in case of Existing user, it will `next()` the value.

Comment: I prefer using Reactive form module for the form validations.

Comment: not sure I understand, for validation I prefer that too, but it would require an async validator right? for just a single input? isn't worth keeping the code already existing and use that instead?

Comment: Do you have only single input in the whole application? If you use no of input fields in your whole application then ReactiveFormModule will be part of common.js and will be loaded at the first instance. Secondly I prefer to create Custom input component that support all validations and handle error messaging within component and further add support for additional features like prefix or suffix inside input element using content projection. This will help you achieving loose coupling and definitely a single change will be required for any kind of requirement change in future

Answer (score 0):

A `BehaviorSubject` is used to store a variable. It works just like an `Observable` but you can access its latest value whenever you want.

The `async` pipe is used to render values from asynchronous sources such as `Observable` or `BehaviorSubject` or a `Subject`.

Note: a `Subject` does not store the latest value as opposed to a `BehaviorSubject`.

Service

```
public error$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

....

this.error.next(true); // to trigger a new error
```

Component

```
<div *ngIf="service.error$ | async">Error<div>
```

Comment: I also answered to my question after following the advice of a user, would my solution be basically the same as yours, just without a new BehaviorSubject? As now I made it an observable<boolean> so I can use the return to show an error?

Comment: I think it's up to you to decide which one you prefer 